# Best practices to handle large-scale binary classification

Tags: logistic, classification, large-data

I have a large training file (~2.4GB, ~31k rows). Each row contains around ~40k binary features, and the label is binary as well.

I tried to use default sklearn logistic regression (loading dataset with pandas), but it is too slow (6 hours and still continue).

What are some good practices to deal with this problem?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Your question focuses on run-time, but that's not the only problem here. With ~40k predictors on ~31k observations, an ordinary logistic regression model is going to be extremely overfit. It's hard to say what a better approach would be without knowing much about the data set or anything about the substantive problem you're working on.

Comment: Does these 40k binary features result from dummy coding of categorical variables? Is so, could you say the number of original categorical variables?

Comment: Can you if you are using regularization? Datasets with more features than lines often don't converge (in a reasonable time) without regularization.

Comment: Thanks a lot your comments. I will try with regularization and see what happens.